# WordPress Custom Post Type Taxonomy Archive URL Rewrite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, permalinks

I have an archive page for a custom post type in a specific taxonomy. This can be achieved creating a taxonomy template under the naming structure of `taxonomy-[custom_taxonomy_slug].php`

The end URL for my archive page is `http://mysite.con/taxonomy/term/?post_type=post_type`

I'm hoping to write an htaccess rule that will allow my URLs to read `/taxonomy/term/post_type/` instead of having the query parameter included. Also, what would be the equivalent on Nginx?

I have tried something like this so far with no luck:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /taxonomy/term/?post_type=$1 [L]`

But I am really not good with regular expressions or htaccess rewriting, so it's no wonder that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an htaccess rule, you need to add a new rewrite rule using WordPress rewrite API.

```
function yourplugin_custom_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule("^taxonomy/([^/]+)/([^/]+)",'index.php?post_type=$matches[2]&taxonomy=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init','yourplugin_custom_rewrite');
```

replace "taxonomy" with your custom taxonomy slug and it will do the job.